# Pass a list of values from a variable into IN statement sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to pass a **list** list1:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
```

into a **spark.sql** statement

```
spark.sql(f'select * from tbl where id IN list1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to format it correctly, and will be more trickier if you use the strings instead of numbers.

If you use PySpark, then it's better to use [isin function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) instead, with something like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
list1 = [1,2,3]
df = spark.read.table("tbl").filter(F.col("id").isin(*list1)
```

then you can use different data types the same way

Comment: but that means it will look my entire sql table and then perform the filter on it ? say i have a table with 100K distinct user Ids and I want to only import into a spark df a list of 10 values. would that solution be the most optimal ?

Comment: Your SQL code & my code are equivalent - Spark will try to read only necessary data, but it depends on the data layout, partitioning, and other things. You can compare plans by adding `.explain()` to both variants

Answer (score 3):

One way is to convert the list to tuple.

```
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> str = r'select * from tbl where id in ' + format(tuple(list1))
>>> str
'select * from tbl where id in (1, 2, 3)'
```

Comment: if you have one element in the list, it throws an error because one element tuples needs a comma at the end, how do we account for that ?